# JAVA - Class/ main class not finding each other. Directory issue?

Tags: java

I am having problems connecting my `SalesMain.java` and `SalesCalc.java` files together so that they can use each other.

And here is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: salescalc.SalesCalc
   at salescalc.SalesMain.main(SalesMain.java:14) Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: salescalc.SalesCalc
   at salescalc.SalesMain.main(SalesMain.java:14) Java Result: 1
```

I am really new to Java so this is all a lot for me.

Here is the code to the [**Main**](http://www.ideone.com/4JIsWt) and [**Sales**](http://www.ideone.com/feTCua) files.

Answer (score 0):

Add `package salescalc;` at the beginning of `SalesCalc`.

They must be in the same package, otherwise you need to import it.

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed it but now I am getting this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - not a statement
 at salescalc.SalesMain.main(SalesMain.java:102)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 36 seconds)

Comment: You have a /> in your code, it shouldn't be there. You muse use an IDE that gives you more information, highlighting errors, etc. Try using Eclipse.

Comment: No, don't use an IDE to hold your hand.  Learn how to read exceptions and stack traces.  Then use an IDE to make your life easier when you have learned more.

Comment: I don't think they are opposite. Finding the /> in the code is very time-consuming without an IDE. I don't see why it would be better to manually find that kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

SalesMain is in the package salescalc and SalesCalc is not in any package at all.  The easiest solution would be to put them both in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using NetBeans IDE. To get around this problem you have to uncheck "Compile on save" setting in the project properties (Build -> Compiling).

Check this out: http://forums.netbeans.org/post-45324.html